# Can't bind spawn-fcgi to address

Tags: bind, spawn-fcgi

Following some [nice instructions](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid) I am almost through setting up PHP to run on nginx. However, every time I try to start spawn-fcgi I get an error message

```
demo@desktop:/usr/bin$ sudo /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start
spawn-fcgi: bind failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

My /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi startup script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHP_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/php-fastcgi
FASTCGI_USER=demo
RETVAL=0
case "$1" in
    start)
      su - $FASTCGI_USER -c $PHP_SCRIPT
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    stop)
      killall -9 php5-cgi
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    restart)
      killall -9 php5-cgi
      su - $FASTCGI_USER -c $PHP_SCRIPT
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: php-fastcgi {start|stop|restart}"
      exit 1
  ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
console output
```

which loads /usr/bin/php-fastcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 6 -u demo -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

One thing to note is that I am running the PHP cgi as the user "demo" which is my account.

**update**

I manually ran the spawn-fcgi command and it worked. Strange...

```
sudo /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -C 6 -u demo -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something else listening on port 9000?

```
netstat -tnap | grep LIST | grep 9000
```

On the other hand, I'd recommend to strace the start script to check the system calls:

```
sudo strace -f -o strace.output /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start
```

Then take a look at the file `strace.output`, especially the last few lines. `strace` is always good to "enlighten" the way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: netstat returns nothing and I think if the port was used spawn-fcgi would say something like "port already in use". I tried strace and ended up with a file thousands and thousands of lines long. O_o

Comment: @Xenocross: Indeed, but I've seen some misleading error messages confusing ports and address :)

Comment: The netstat command should read:
        netstat -tnap | grep LIST | grep 9000